# UnicodeDecodeError Ipython Jupyter - excel

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

I'm trying to convert a particular dataframe `headlamp_crack` to excel by using the following script:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('headexcel.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
headlamp_crack.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index='False')
writer.save()
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 99: 
invalid start byte
```

How can I fix that?

Just an information, I'm using Ipython Jupyter
Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead using `pd.ExcelWriter`, have you tried simply using a one-liner of `headlamp_crack.to_excel('headexcel.xlsx', index=False)` ?  Does it throw the same error?

Comment: Can you identify the row(s) in `headlamp_crack` that are throwing the error?  You can use `encode()` and `decode()`, or even the native `encoding` argument in [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html), but it'll be easier to help if you can provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same erro using the `headlamp_crack.to_excel('headexcel.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: The line 99 is below (Comment Column):
'CLIENTE RELATA FAROL DESCASCANDO\nSUBSTITUIR FARoIS DIANTEIROS LADO DIREITO E ESQUERDO EM GARANTIA\nVERIFICADO E DIAGOSTICADO QUE OS FARoIS DIANTEIROS ESTaO DESCASCANDO DEVIDO A FALHA NO MATERIAL\nCLIENTE RELATA FAROL DESCASCANDO\nSUBSTITUIR FARoIS DIANTEIROS LADO DIREITO E ESQUERDO EM GARANTIA\nVERIFICADO E DIAGOSTICADO QUE OS FARoIS DIANTEIROS ESTaO DESCASCANDO DEVIDO A FALHA NO MATERIAL'